# How to a put a textarea next to an image and have it fill up rest of the space?

Tags: html, css, image, textarea

I'm trying to make nice comment box. I want to show an image before the textarea in one line/row. The image size should be fixed. The textarea should fill up the rest of the space. The website has dynamic width, so fixing the textarea width doesn't work for me.

But the text area will not go next to the image, but it will go under it.

```
<img src="http://i2.wp.com/c0589922.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/avatars/male200.png" style="float:left;"/>
<textarea style="float: left; height: 200px; margin-left: 210px; width:100%"></textarea>
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8ebm/17/).

Any ideas on how to achieve this? [Check out the comment box at cnn.com to see what I'm talking about](http://www.cnn.com/2013/02/08/tech/social-media/apparently-this-matters-face-tattoos/index.html?hpt=hp_c2).

Comment: The code you posted and the code in the fiddle is not the same!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W8ebm/17/ Sorry about that

Comment: are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6shan/

Comment: Yes, but I want textarea to fill up the rest of the space on the right.

Comment: use CSS width property in textarea with any values which match your space.

Comment: @SeongYupYoo - http://jsfiddle.net/6shan/1/ use percentages on a fluid layout or fixed pixels on a fixed layout. Simple as that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6shan/2/

Comment: @TharangaNuwan The width of the site is dynamic. It changes.

Comment: @godesign Is there a way to keep the image size fixed?

Comment: @SeongYupYoo check godesign's updated jsfiddle

Comment: use CSS width and height with appropriate values in pixel to make image size fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will do what you want to do:

```
<div style="position:absolute; left:100px; right:100px;">
  <div style="position:relative;">
    <img src="http://i2.wp.com/c0589922.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/
          avatars/male200.png" style="position:absolute;">
    <div style="position: absolute; left:210px; right:0px; top:0px;">
      <input type="textbox" style="width:100%; height:200px; display:block;
          padding:0;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Some fine-tuning may be needed. My answer is based on this post: http://jsfiddle.net/QaWMN/2/.

Answer (score 0):

try this

HTML CODE :

```
<div>
   <img src="http://i2.wp.com/c0589922.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/avatars/male200.png" />
    <textarea cols="20" rows="4"></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
div img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

div textarea {
    width: 80%; // adjust this value you need
}
```

Comment: I need the textarea to be fluid width, and image size to be fixed.

Comment: This is getting close, thought not 100%. When I shrink the width down very small, then textarea still goes to the bottom, but this is pretty close. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/6shan/

Here is the html :

```
<div class="comment">
    <div class="avatarContainer">
    <img class="avatar" src="http://i2.wp.com/c0589922.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/avatars/male200.png"></img>
    </div>
        <div class="commentBody">
        <div class="commentHeader">commentHeader</div>
        <textarea class="commentText">commentText</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the accompanying css :

```
.comment
{height:150px; width:250px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:15px;
}
.avatar 
{ height:px; width:24px;}
.avatarContainer
{ height:150px; width:30px;float:left;}
.commentBody
{ height:150px;width:220px;float:right;}
.commentHeader
{height:30px; width:100%; margin-left:10px; border-bottom:1px solid black;}
.commentText 
{ height:100px; width:100%;
margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;}
```

Comment: I need the textarea needs to be fluid in width and image width to be fixed. So when image size stays the same whether the window is small or large, but the textarea shrink and expand with the resizing of the window.

Comment: changing both height and width of the textArea to auto or a percentage should accomplish. Image size is hardcoded in pixels so it will not change size.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit weird, but this will do the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/6shan/4/

Using position absolute for the img and for the textarea inside a relative div.

```
<div>
    <img src="..."/>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100px;
}

div img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
}

div textarea {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 110px; /* 100px of the image's width plus 10px margin */
    right: 0px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I just found out that this doesn't work in FireFox and IE. It only works in Chrome and Safari. Any ideas on how to get it working in FF and IE as well?

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found to do it without using the position: absolute is the following:

```css
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.wrap {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 100px;
}
textarea {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i2.wp.com/c0589922.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/avatars/male200.png"/>
<div class="wrap">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```